# Voice effect ring modulator for Android

Tags: android, audio, native

Hi I have tried to implement a ring modulator in native C for Android. I need to manipulate wav files for a voice changer app. I want to get effects like the dalek voice.
This is what I have done so far:
Read the wav file   - Works
Iterate through every sample of the wav - Works
Save the new samples - Works

For a ring modulator the audio file has to the combined with a sinus, so i tried this:

```
//Position through the sine wave as a percentage (i.e. 0 to 1 is 0 to 2*PI)
double cyclePosition = 0;
double fFreq = 1;   // Frequency of sine wave in hz
double cycleInc = fFreq/16000;  // Fraction of cycle between samples

for(i=0; i<csize; i++)
{
    currentSample = //read it;
    currentSample = currentSample* sin(2*M_PI*cyclePosition));
    currentSample = //write it;
    cyclePosition += cycleInc;
    if (cyclePosition > 1)
        cyclePosition -= 1;
}
```

So the problem is that if I enter a frequency of 1Hz, every 1 second there is a very loud hissing in the audio. And if I change the frequency to 30Hz for example I can not understand anything from the originally audio.
Do anyone have an idea how to improve this?

Comment: I assume the samplerate is fixed at 16kHz?

Comment: This is clearly not your actual code since there is a stray/extra closing parentheses on the second line of your loop. Can you double check it please? Also, what is the datatype of currentSample? Another thing to check would be logging the output of both cyclePosition and the sin to see if they output what you expect.

Comment: The samplerate is fixed. The datatype of currentSample is short. I do not know what I should expect. The only thing I know is that the ring modulation is achieved by combining the audio with a sinus wave.

Answer (score 0):

The code as-is, looks fine to me, but as I said I don't think this is your actual code. Please double-check. An example of a test you could run is to comment-out the multiplication line:

```
...

for(i=0; i<csize; i++)
{
    currentSample = //read it;
    //currentSample = currentSample* sin(2*M_PI*cyclePosition));
    currentSample = //write it;
    cyclePosition += cycleInc;
    if (cyclePosition > 1)
        cyclePosition -= 1;
}
```

That should output exactly what you put in. Then try things that seem innocuous:

```
currentSample = currentSample * .99;
```

should make almost no audible difference and

```
currentSample = currentSample * .5;
```

should halve the volume.

Comment: OK I have tried it and this are the results: Nearly no change with 0.99 but 0.5 did not halve the volume. Actually it seems a bit louder and it sounds as spoken into a walkie talkie. Does the value of a sample indicate the volume of the wav file? Where is the tone pitch saved in the wav file?

Comment: Based on your responses, it's clear that something is wrong in code you have not shown. Probably an endian issue, but that's a guess. As to your other question, there are plenty of answers online. Try wikipedia, eg: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation